# How can I seperate picture and text? Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I use flex and I want to separate text and picture like in example [click to look example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUBhD.png) because now they are sticky. How can I do this because margin dont work? Code below. Thanks for help!

**CODE:**

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

#section {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#div{
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  height: 399px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <section id="section">
        <div id="div">
          <h1>H1</h1>
          <p>some text</p>
        </div>
        <img src="aplle.jpg">
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the reason why it is not workign as your pictrue descripes is a wrong css line. You want the text block and the picture to be 100px apart. for that the css line should be added `#div {margin-right: 100px;}`. YOur css-line declares a margin left of 100px which will add the margin left of the box not to the right as intended.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have a margin on the right, however its not the best way to do it as it is not responsive.

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}


#section {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#div{
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: 100px;

    height: 399px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section id="section">
      <div id="div">
        <h1>H1</h1>
        <p>some text</p>
      </div>
      <img src="aplle.jpg">
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: correct that solevs the problem the easiest way as I already mentioned befor int he comments. But you're worng with stating that it will not be responsive that way. It will break at somepoint yes, so you simply need to add media breakpoitns to stay full responsive.

Comment: Yes @tacoshy, however there's a shorter and better practice on adding spaces between, using flexboxes, media is a longer way but still does the trick

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :)

you can add **padding-left** of image **50px** and **padding-right** of div **50px** to get separation.

Also make it responsive add this `flex-direction:column;` to section @640 media queries, That is

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
  #section {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:black;
}


#section {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#div{
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 399px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-right:50px;
}
img{
  background:#fff;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display:block;
  padding-left:50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:640px){
  #section {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <section id="section">
      <div id="div">
        <h1>H1</h1>
        <p>some text</p>
      </div>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Kvy.png">
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: far to complicated and a bad habit. Simply create a margin to either the pciture or the div. Why make stuff mroe complicated as it ahs to be? For that you needed to add 7 additional lines of code when one line at the right place would have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Give 50% width to your #div and img each they will not overlap each other

```
#div {
  width: 50%;
}
#section img {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Full code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-haze-4cyf2?file=/style.css:218-396